# RSpec Stub same method in loop

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

Using RSpec, I want to:

```
expect(Thing).to receive(:status)
                .with(for: 'something')
                .and_return('down')
```

on the first iteration, and the same stub should return a different return on the 2nd iteration:

```
expect(Thing).to receive(:status)
                .with(for: 'something')
                .and_return('up')
```

when testing the below code snippet:

```
2.times do |i|
  break if Thing.status(for: 'something') == 'up'
  sleep 2
  raise MyError if i > 0
end
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just stub once and supply [all the return values](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls).

```
expect(Thing).to receive(:status)
                .with(for: 'something')
                .and_return('down', 'up')
```

First time `status` is called, it will return `'down'`. Second time it will return `'up'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple return values when stubbing rspec method calls

see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls